# Javascript does not continue after adding stylesheet to a class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display a div container if the device has a special width. I made a simple if-condition and it is working well.

I wanted to add a second function to my code and the function was not called. After trying out I saw that the code stops after the document.getElementyById-Code.

If the alert("Hello World") is called in the if-condition **before** the getElementById, it is called. If it is called in the if-condition **after** the getElementById, it is not called anymore.

Why is the progress stuck there?

The console output:
[Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("whitecontainer").style')
    setHeightandWidth (-Link deleted-, line 402)
    onresize (-Link deleted-, line 382)

but the object cannot be null, because the style change does work, it is just stuck after doing the resize.

Thanks for help!

```
function setHeightandWidth() {
    var body = document.body,
        html = document.documentElement;

    var height = (Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
                           html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight) - 75 - 248);

    var width = document.body.clientWidth;

    if (width < 1199) {
        document.getElementById("whitecontainer").style.display = "none";

        alert("Hello World!");

    }

    if (width >= 1199) {
        width = 1140;
        document.getElementById("whitecontainer").style.display = "inherit";
    }

    var white_container = document.getElementById("whitecontainer");
    white_container.style.height = height + "px";
    white_container.style.width = width + "px";

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant html?

Comment: Can you be more precise, which part is not working?

Comment: The code like it is there is not displaying Hello World. If I put the alert("Hello World!") above the document.getElementById, it displays Hello World.

Comment: Some Fiddle coding would help...

Comment: Why not use [CSS media queries??](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: Have you looked at console output? if you don't have an element with id == whitecontainer, then you would get an uncaught exception with this line: document.getElementById("whitecontainer").style.display = "none";

Comment: [Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("whitecontainer").style')
 setHeightandWidth (-Deleted link-, line 402)
 onresize (-Deleted link-, line 382)

But setting the height and width for this element does actually work.

Comment: When do you run this script ... after the document loads?

Comment: Make sure "whitecontainer" is spelled corectly in your html .     https://jsfiddle.net/awjra2xa/ this code works , but if you change the id in the html the alert won't be called

Comment: @ Andrei Maieras - The fiddle appears to have errors in the mark up ... unclosed and missing tags.

Comment: @Skalibran - As steve already said, you need to post your html.  Without that information it is difficult to find the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The alert not working probably means that the line before it caused an error.

Do the lines

```
white_container.style.height = height + "px";
white_container.style.width = width + "px";
```

Run?

I have a feeling your code fails everytime you use document. XXXXXX

'whitecontainer' is probably not a real element

Comment: Yes, that is the last thing that is working. After that the code is stuck, so I'm not able to change anything else using my javascript.

Comment: Wait do you mean that white_container.style.height = height + "px";
white_container.style.width = width + "px"; IS running?

Comment: exactly. The console throws out a null-exception for whitecontainer anyway. EDIT: NO, it is not. I just checked it again and now it is not working anymore, but the code you mentioned should run without problems if not stuck. I use it in some projects.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in this line

document.getElementById("whitecontainer").style.display

javascript is unable to find id "whitecontainer" tat's why it throws an null exception and script breaks

Comment: Seems exactly like this, but the code you mentioned above is working.